# How can I find out how many hours a hard drive has been running (powered on hours, or POH) on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, unix, ssd

Where can I view hard disk usage stats on Mac OS X?  Specifically it's a SMART enabled SSD (Crucial M4).  But hopefully this command and/or app will not be so picky with drive type.

CrystalDiskInfo was recommended but it is not available for Mac or Unix.

Comment: The tool I generally use under Linux or FreeBSD is called hdparm ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/hdparm/ ). There seems to be no port of it yet for OS/X, but searching for possible port I found these: http://serverfault.com/questions/40300/hdparm-on-os-x and http://missig.org/julian/projects/macosx/ (diskutil part) --- (All not a real answer, so posted in a comment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SMART attribute 09 (Power-On Hours) is the one that tells you how many hours a device has been running. Anything that can dump SMART info should be able to get it for you. There are several utilities for OS X that claim to do just that, including the Linux favorite `smartctl`.

Comment: Thanks!  I found what I needed earlier, but this answer will likely serve others better.

Answer (score 1):

[Trim Enabler](http://www.groths.org/?page_id=322) worked for my SSD, but it won't work for HDD.